# Can answer lots of questions on here but seem to be not allowed to comment. I guess people don't want answers?

Tags: support, answers, comments

Someone asked how to stop the accessibility menu from appearing when they turned on their phone and I have an answer for that: "go to settings and find appear on top turn off accessibility and it will stop appearing every time you turn on your phone."

However, I can't post the answer. Why is that?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, [welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour).

I'd assume the question in question is [Accessibility menu keeps appearing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/161806/accessibility-menu-keeps-appearing). As mentioned on the banner, the question was [protected](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) because it gathered low-quality answers, or even posts that are not really solving the question, and thus a minimum [reputation](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) of 10 is needed to post an answer.

The restriction is kind of unfortunate but sometimes needed because new users sometimes are not familiar with how this site works as a Q&A site, where "Answer" is *only* for answering the question (i.e. not for asking clarification, mentioning they have the same problem, etc.) and instead treat it like a discussion forum where they can post almost anything.

As for being not able to comment, this is because [commenting everywhere needs 50 reputations](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for the same reason that new users may misuse the comment, or worse, post something offensive/spammy and not get detected (because comment doesn't bump the Q&A thread).

So, it is not that people don't want answers, but sometimes a minimum level of barrier to entry is needed to prevent the site from getting overwhelmed by over-moderation tasks.

**That said, I have unprotected the question** so that anyone (including you!) can post an answer to that question now. Sorry for the rough beginning. Hopefully, you can understand the reasoning, and also looking forward to your future contribution.